# Runtime error while expanding a Listadapter

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I am writing this code to have a custom list in android. I am using

> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

My current code is trying to show a `listview` that includes image and text, but I guess that doesn't matter.

**FourthFragment.java**

```
public class FourthFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<Weather>  weatherProperties = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth, container, false);
        //create our property elements
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(10, "Smith Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A large 3 bedroom apartment right in the heart of Sydney! A rare find, with 3 bedrooms and a secured car park.", 450.00, "property_image_1", 3, 1, 1));
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(66, "King Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A fully furnished studio apartment overlooking the harbour. Minutes from the CBD and next to transport, this is a perfect set-up for city living.", 320.00, "property_image_2", 1, 1, 1));
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(1, "Liverpool Road", "Liverpool", "NSW", "A standard 3 bedroom house in the suburbs. With room for several cars and right next to shops this is perfect for new families.", 360.00, "property_image_3", 3, 2, 2));
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(567, "Sunny Street", "Gold Coast", "QLD", "Come and see this amazing studio apartment in the heart of the gold coast, featuring stunning waterfront views.", 360.00, "property_image_4" , 1, 1, 1));

        TextView tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
        tv.setText("My Header");
//        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));
        // New Array Adapters
        ArrayAdapter<Weather> adapter = new weatherArrayAdapter(getContext(), 0, weatherProperties);
        //Find list view and bind it with the custom adapter
        ListView listView = (ListView) tv.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return myFragmentView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // on click display the item in toast
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (String)l.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    static FourthFragment newInstance(int num) {
        FourthFragment fourthFragment = new FourthFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        fourthFragment.setArguments(args);

        return fourthFragment;
    }


    //custom ArrayAdapater
    class weatherArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

        private Context context;
        private List<Weather> weatherProperties;

        //constructor, call on creation
        public weatherArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Weather> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);

            this.context = context;
            this.weatherProperties = objects;
        }

        //called when rendering the list
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //get the weather we are displaying
            Weather weather = weatherProperties.get(position);

            //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //conditionally inflate either standard or special template
            View view;

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_layout, null);


            TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
            TextView bedroom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
            TextView bathroom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bathroom);
            TextView carspot = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carspot);
            TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

            //set address and description
            String completeAddress = weather.getStreetNumber() + " " + weather.getStreetName() + ", " + weather.getSuburb() + ", " + weather.getState();
            address.setText(completeAddress);

            //display trimmed excerpt for description
            int descriptionLength = weather.getDescription().length();
            if(descriptionLength >= 100){
                String descriptionTrim = weather.getDescription().substring(0, 100) + "...";
                description.setText(descriptionTrim);
            }else{
                description.setText(weather.getDescription());
            }

            //set price and weather attributes
            price.setText("$" + String.valueOf(weather.getPrice()));
            bedroom.setText("Bed: " + String.valueOf(weather.getBedrooms()));
            bathroom.setText("Bath: " + String.valueOf(weather.getBathrooms()));
            carspot.setText("Car: " + String.valueOf(weather.getCarspots()));

            //get the image associated with this weather
            int imageID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(weather.getImage(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(imageID);

            return view;
        }
    }


}
```

There is no `compiletime` error, but this is giving me `runtime` error as

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

   at com.example.phocast.FourthFragment.onCreateView(FourthFragment.java:39)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

I will be grateful if you kindly show me the problem.

**UPDATE after the answers and comments**

The error is here: (sorry for putting this as quote, otherwise SO doesnt allow me to submit as `mostly code error`)

> ```
> TextView tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
> tv.setText("My Header");
> ```

and the `xml` is:

**weather_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="Property Image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Street Address"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pricingSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoSection"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bedroom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/price"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="Bed:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bathroom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/price"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bedroom"
            android:text="Bath:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carspot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/price"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bathroom"
            android:text="Car:" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2: fragment_four.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/customListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="gravity">
    </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE3**
So, I have created a **fourth_fragment.xml** as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and changed the line:

```
tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
          tv.setText("My Header");
```

But I am still getting the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

Comment: What's your line 39 of your FourthFragment class?

Comment: In which line are you getting error, please post that line of code @BaRud

Comment: post R.layout.weather_layout xml and check textview ids. And what is **tv.findViewById(R.id.customListView);**

Comment: Please check whether your layout `R.layout.fragment_fourth` has the specified id i.e `R.id.bedroom`

Comment: Can you post your 'fragment_fourth.xml'

Comment: @Abhishekkumar: added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `null` over here. Check whether you have `TextView id` =  `bedroom` or not in layout `fragment_fourth`

```
  TextView tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
  tv.setText("My Header");
```

Your **Error** :

> 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference

Its issue of `Id` of your `TextView`,The variable `tv` is probably `null` and you call the `setText` method on that `null`, which you can't.

And **Modify your code like this :**

```
TextView tv; //Global Variable

      tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
      tv.setText("My Header");
```

**Try also :** Clean your project & Rebuilt it.

Change your fragmentfour.xml code : (Put `ScrollView` if needed)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/yourTextView_layout)" />

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/customListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="gravity">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Update your Fragment java class :

```
ListView listView;//globally
TextView tv;


     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth, container, false);

  listView = (ListView) tv.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        //create our property elements
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(10, "Smith Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A large 3 bedroom apartment right in the heart of Sydney! A rare find, with 3 bedrooms and a secured car park.", 450.00, "property_image_1", 3, 1, 1));
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(66, "King Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A fully furnished studio apartment overlooking the harbour. Minutes from the CBD and next to transport, this is a perfect set-up for city living.", 320.00, "property_image_2", 1, 1, 1));
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(1, "Liverpool Road", "Liverpool", "NSW", "A standard 3 bedroom house in the suburbs. With room for several cars and right next to shops this is perfect for new families.", 360.00, "property_image_3", 3, 2, 2));
        weatherProperties.add(new Weather(567, "Sunny Street", "Gold Coast", "QLD", "Come and see this amazing studio apartment in the heart of the gold coast, featuring stunning waterfront views.", 360.00, "property_image_4" , 1, 1, 1));

         tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.bedroom);
        tv.setText("My Header");
//        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));
        // New Array Adapters
        ArrayAdapter<Weather> adapter = new weatherArrayAdapter(getContext(), 0, weatherProperties);
        //Find list view and bind it with the custom adapter

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return myFragmentView;
    }
```

Comment: this does not change anything. I am still getting the same error on same line.

Comment: Can you please post your fragment_fourth.xml

Comment: There is no textview is in your fourth_fragment.xml with id bedroom, your bedroom id textview is in weather_layout.xml @BaRud

Comment: Actually , you are attaching layout fragment_four to you FragmentFour.java , you need to create a textview inside your four_fragment.xml

Comment: But I want to display the weather_fragment. So, instead of creating a textview, can I attach the existing listview?

Comment: After adding the textview as @+id/bedroom, I am getting error as:
                                                                     `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`, i.e.
        `ListView listView = (ListView) tv.findViewById(R.id.customListView);`

Comment: weatherLayout.xml if you xml of list you can not use any view from there in youy main fragment . for this you have to create a new textview inside your fourfragment.xml, Every Java class have a layout we can use only widgets of that layout not others.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didnt got you. Can you please show me what to do?

Comment: Every Fragment have a xml file, we attaching by findViewById. and we can use use only the buttons, textview,edittext of that xml only. Here you have two xml you can use only contents of your fourthfragment widgets to your FragmentFour.java , you have only listview inside your fragment_four , no textview , bedroom id textview is inside weather_layout . So create a textview inside four_fragment.xml with id bedroom @BaRud

Comment: Did you meant that should be my xml?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not getting you ? @BaRud

Comment: since in your xml that you have posted, you gave    `layout="@layout/yourTextView_layout)" `, i have created the xml, in update 3. kindly have a look.

Comment: now, its seems good, Now its ok @BaRud , is your issue resolved ??

Comment: Nope, kindly have a look at the very last line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165210/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-barud).

Comment: i updated my code please check & change accordingly @b

Comment: Hi @abhishek awefully sorry for this late reply....by network dumped me. when you are available next, can we discuss this?

Answer (score 0):

Best you set all values without null in POJO model class.  Apply this it will avoid crash

```
if(weather.getPrice() != null && !weather.getPrice().isEmpty()) 
price.setText("$" + String.valueOf(weather.getPrice()));
if(weather.getBedrooms() != null && !weather.getBedrooms().isEmpty()) 
bedroom.setText("Bed: " + String.valueOf(weather.getBedrooms()));
if(weather.getBathrooms() != null && !weather.getBathrooms().isEmpty()) 
bathroom.setText("Bath: " + String.valueOf(weather.getBathrooms()));
if(weather.getCarspots() != null && !weather.getCarspots().isEmpty()) 
carspot.setText("Car: " + String.valueOf(weather.getCarspots()));
```